# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed - Error with Docker, Django and Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, django-forms

I am new to docker. Starting from a Django project (Django 4.0), I am using Docker to side by side with Nginx.
I used a *docker-compose.yml* file and used a custom configuration of Nginx, and everything works.
Only when I go to the login screen and click the "Login" button it comes up "*Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted*.".
The code inside *login.html* is like this

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button class="btn btn-success ml-2" type="submit">Log In</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check if NGINX is stripping the necessary cookies or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read through all of these settings starting with "CSRF_" [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins)

As you did not provide your settings.py I can only guess that the problem lays in there. Your form template is fine.

Probably my link leads you already to the correct setting, called `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` where you basically input all your domains that you want to trust as a list. (Trust meaning which domain is allowed to send a post request)

settings.py:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://trusted.domain.one.com',
    'https://trusted.domain.two.com'
]
```

If this does not work try also to add the `'http://trusted.domain.one.com'` without the S in httpS.